# How do I fix error "logger" in ReviewBoard?

Tags: perforce, review-board

I'm setting ReviewBoard with Perforce and faced error "logger" when I add new repository for Perforce.

I set Logging from admin page, but no log found in the path, and no error log in apache.

Could you please how to fix the error or how to get the error log ?

Comment: Just a guess, but: the 'logger' facility in Perforce, which reports on updated jobs and changelists, requires that you have 'review' permission on your Perforce server. Perhaps the userid that is running ReviewBoard hasn't been granted review permission on your Perforce server? Ask your Perforce admin to check the Perforce server logs.

Comment: I fixed the issue by installing daemon and refresh install P4PythonInstaller ! Thanks !